# Select Random Distinct Images from a folder php

Tags: php, image, random, directory

I want to select four random images from a folder which contains a number of images.

**What i want to display is a table (2x2) where i can display 4 random distinct images.**

Can someone tell me how can i select random **distinct** files from a folder so that i can store their path in a variable and then can use these variables to display images randomly in the table!

Is there any particular function which can select random files from a folder or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [`glob()`](http://php.net/glob) to get all files from directory.
2. Use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand) to get random entries from an array.

Comment: Can you provide me a small example? @bsdnoobz

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php




    function get_imagess($root) {

    $r = array();
    $r = array();
    $k = glob("$root/*");
    shuffle($k);
    foreach($k as $n) {
        if (is_dir($n)) {
            break;
            //$r = array_merge($r, get_imagesss($n));
            print_r("xxx");
        } else {
           $r[] = $n;
           //print_r($n + "yeah");     
        }
    }
    return $r;
}

    function get_images($root) {

    $r = array();
    $k = glob("$root/*");
    shuffle($k);
    $n = $k[0];
//    foreach($k as $n) {
        if (is_dir($n)) {
            $r = array_merge($r, get_imagess($n));
        } else {
           $r[] = $n;
        }
//    }

    return $r;
}


$files = get_images('.');
//print_r($files);
//break;





shuffle($files);
$true=true;
    $extList = array();
    $extList['gif'] = 'image/gif';
    $extList['jpg'] = 'image/jpeg';
    $extList['jpeg'] = 'image/jpeg';
    $extList['png'] = 'image/png';
        $ass=0;
while($true)
    {
        $ass=$ass+1;
        if($ass>100){$true=false;}
        $imageInfo = pathinfo($files[0]);
        if (isset( $extList[ strtolower( $imageInfo['extension'] ) ] )){

    $temp = substr($files[0], -5);  
    $temp = strtolower($temp);
    if( $temp == "p.jpg"){shuffle($files);}  // checking if jpg has a preview file
    else{  // no preview found
    $true=false;
    //print_r($temp);
    }}
    else
        {
        shuffle($files);
        //print_r('bad' + $temp);
        }
}

//print_r($files[0]);
echo '<HTML><meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="5; URL=./ImageRotateMaybe.php"><img src="';
echo $files[0];
echo ' " width=100%>';
?>
```

Comment: _Why_ is this the correct answer? It just looks like a lot of code... can you explain what's going on?